# Sql row to table conversion query

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I have a typical requirement.

For example, I have following data in a table,

```
*-----------*-----*----*----*----*----*----*----*----*----*
| date      |  x1 | x2 | x3 | y1 | y2 | y3 | z1 | z2 | z3 |
*-----------*-----*----*----*----*----*----*----*----*----*
|2017-05-15 | 11  | 12 |15  | 21 | 31 | 41 | 0.1| 0.4| 0.5|
*-----------*-----*----*----*----*----*----*----*----*----*
```

Now I want write a query that results in following:

```
   date    a1 b1  c1
2017-05-17 11 21 0.1
2017-05-17 12 31 0.4
2017-05-17 15 41 0.5
```

Is it possible? if yes how?

Any help is good.

Comment: All the values are stored in a single column or multiple columns?

Comment: Multiple columns, final result will have in above example 4 columns and 3 rows

Comment: Kindly update the question with the columns. Be specific about the requirements as it would be easy for others to able to analyse and provide solutions.

Comment: sorry for the formatting but hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column format as as per mentioned then i guess this will solve your issue:

```
declare @data table (date varchar(10),x1 int,x2 int,x3 int,y1 int,y2 int,y3 int,z1  numeric(5,2),z2  numeric(5,2),z3 numeric(5,2))

insert into @data values ('2017-05-15',11,12,15,21,31,41,0.1,0.4,0.5)
select date,x1 as 'a1',y1 as 'b1', z1 as 'c1' from @data
union all 
select date,x2 as 'a2',y2 as 'b2', z2 as 'c2' from @data
union all
select date,x3 as 'a3',y3 as 'b3', z3 as 'c3' from @data
```

Result is:

```
|-----------|---|---|-----|
|DATE       |a1 |b1 |c1   |
|-----------|---|---|-----| 
|2017-05-15 |11 |21 |0.10 |
|-----------|---|---|-----| 
|2017-05-15 |12 |31 |0.40 |
|-----------|---|---|-----| 
|2017-05-15 |15 |41 |0.50 |
|-----------|---|---|-----|
```

Comment: Thanks @Ranjana Ghimire union all will solve my problems. thanks a lot.